# Get the intent object in an activity

Tags: android

Following is the scenario.
1. My application has 2 activities.
2. Activity-1 creates an intent object and pass this intent to startActivity method to launch Activity-2
3. After startActivity method Activity-1 gets onPause.

My question here is that can i get the same intent object in my onPause method without making intent object a part of my class i.e. I know android provides API to get the intent which is used to launch the activity. That means i can get this intent object in Activity-2 but can i get it in Activity-1 also after i used the function startActivity.

Thanks
Dalvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) method has no arguments. Therefore all objects that it will operate on must either be class members or belong to a global/static object.

Is there a reason that you don't want this to be a part of your class? This will be the easiest and proper way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

i asume that you wana get some data in first from second activity.

use [Activity.startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and override onActivityResult 
like [here](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Android-Activity-startActivityForResult-387002) you can also return Intent there by changing `setResult(RESULT_OK, null)` to `setResult(RESULT_OK, YourNewIntent)`