# Android: Updating SharedPrefereces on activity resume doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, onresume

I've got an "activity a" which reads some values from `SharedPreferences` and display them in a `TextView`, then I call "activity b" where the values from `SharedPreferences` get updated and written back to `SharedPreferences`. Finally I go back to "activity a" by pressing the back-button, now the new (updated) values should be read from `SharedPreferences` and shown in the `TextView`. But here comes the problem, the values just read from `SharedPreferences` are still not updated (are not the new ones set by activity b) (got it from logcat output), how comes that? Does `SharedPrefs` need some kind of manual refresh?

If I restart "activity a" everything works just fine and the new values are shown properly. What's the matter?

I call the method to read and show the values from `onResume()` in "activity a".

I also tried to re-instantiate the SharedPrefs-Object (with `getSharedPreferences()`) but it doesn't help either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's definitely written into SharedPref because the new value is shown, but only after the Activity/App is restarted.

Comment: hmmm what about getSharedPreferences() only in onCreate registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and unregiser in onDestroy

and do the changes in Listener ?

Comment: have you written it in the onRestart method... if so hope it could work...

Comment: Hmmm i found out, if I commit the changes to SharedPrefs from onBackPressed() instead of onDestroy() in the Activity B it works just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling the commit() method in activity b to save the new values.

Eg something like:

```
SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("abcprefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
editor.putString("key", "val");
editor.commit();
```

And secondly you can finish() the activity a before being sent to activity b, then from activity b a new instance of activity a will be created and onCreate() will be called.

Alternatively you can refresh the preferences in the onStart() because your activity is probably "no longer visible" when sent to activity b.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html to see the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Furthermore, some implementations of Android will go through a Pause/Resume cycle twice, the second cycle starting before any changes can be committed. I have spent <i>days</i> trying to debug the failure of a flag to be saved (I was using apply(), which is asynchronous.) on a Samsung running 8.0.0 when the app worked perfectly well on a Moto G running 5.1. For important stuff that is application wide, always commit, never apply.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` is not for sharing data between Activities

Use `Intent` and `Activity.startActivityForResult`.  See my answer here
[Get the intent object in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276783/get-the-intent-object-in-an-activity/6276955#6276955)

Comment: I know, but i need the values to be in SharedPrefs so every activity within the app can query them

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're using the same preferences throughout each of your activities: if you're using `getSharedPreferences`, you should specify the file and level of access.  In your case, it sounds like `getDefaultSharedPreferences` would be the way to go.

Also, make sure that you're not only setting the preferences, but also committing the changes:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

and then in your other activities:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean myPreference = preferences.getBoolean("key", defaultValue);
```

This would be easier to help with if you would post the pieces of code in question; if you're still unable to get it working, I would try adding it to your post.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that preference.edit() returns a different `SharedPreferences.Editor` each time you call it, so it's important to store the editor into a separate variable, use it to write out the preferences and then commit that editor. E.g. this won't work:

```
myPrefs.edit().putInt("pref", 1);
myPrefs.edit().putBoolean("pref", true);
myPrefs.edit().commit();
```

It needs to be (as has been demonstrated):

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt("pref", 1);
editor.putBoolean("pref", true);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to update your activity A with data sent to the SharedPreferences from activity B while resuming the activity A from B, do the following:

1. In your app manifest, set the activity A "launchMode" to "standard"
2. On finishing from the activity B and returning to activity A, add an intent flag of "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" to your intent like below:

   Intent intent = new Intent(activityB.this, activityA.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();

**To explain the Code:** The "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" checks if activity A being started is already running in the current task, then instead of launching the new instance of that Activity, all the other activities on top of it is destroyed and this intent is delivered to the resumed instance of the Activity (now on top), through onNewIntent method. Follow this link to learn more about android task and back stack: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-task-and-back-stack-review-5017f2c18196

Hope this helps...