# Android FullScreen Activity Programmatically

Tags: android

I know that I can acheive that with:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I have a `Settings Activity`, where the user can set `Fullscreen mode`. When he comes back to the `Main Activity`, of course if he checked Fullscreen, the Activity must resume Fullscreen.

How to do this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As u are using this which must be used before setContentView(int). i think give a try ur getWindow().setFlags() in onResume() alternatively i am giving a link which might help u for ur case.U can set condition before setting or removing those.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

You can use following link for your purpose which is doing the same for android 4.4 or below.Android 4.4 (API Level 19) introduces a new SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE flag for setSystemUiVisibility() that lets your app go truly "full screen. For lower ver as well link has some workaround by setting flags u can use.

```
  https://developer.android.com/samples/ImmersiveMode/src/com.example.android.immersivemode/ImmersiveModeFragment.html
```

for remove flags u also have **clearFlag()** which u added for purpose when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could create a `SharedPreferences` ([Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) - [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)) to check if the user set the `Fullscreen mode`, and check this in the `onStart or onRestart method's Activity`, when you come back to the `Main Activity`.

And if doesn't work (as you can see here: [Updating SharedPrefereces on activity resume doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293539/android-updating-sharedprefereces-on-activity-resume-doesnt-work)), this answer might help you: [Call finish() when the Second Activity is lauched](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293705/2668136).

Hope you will have the expected result.

Comment: Hi, this is what i would like to do but i have to use:
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); before setContentView() and this is the real problem :(

Comment: You can recycle the activity?