# Full screen android app without statusbar and system navigationbar

Tags: android

I want to enable and to disable statusbar and navigation bar in my android app. For this i use next methods:

```
private void hideSystemUi() {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }



private void showSystemUi() {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
```

where

```
decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
```

It works okay: these methods show and hide statusbar with navigationbar, BUT there is the problem: when statusbar is hide, i can to show it with top-bottom swipe in top part of my screen; similar situation with navigationbar. So , how to resolve this? I want to disable these system view fully, without possibility to show them with swipe. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android FullScreen Activity Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024779/android-fullscreen-activity-programmatically)

Comment: no, there is no question about top-bottom swipe for status bar in that theme

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. From my knowledge, it's actually intended that the user always has the option to access the status bar, even when only temporarily via the top-bottom swipe. So I think your current solution is already the best you can get.